# Avoid updating non nullable field

Tags: entity-framework, .net-4.5, entity-framework-5

When updating a row from a detached entity, I'm trying to avoid updating fields which haven't changed, using this:

```
DbEntityEntry<Type> entry = context.Entry(entity);
entry.Property(p => p.Property).IsModified = false;
```

This works fine for nullable fields, but when it's a non nullable field EF throws a validation exception saying that the field is required.

Anyone have any insight into why this doesn't work and if I must fiddle around with original values to overcome it?
I'm using EF 5.0 and the DBContext-API.

Comment: I added EF5 and .NET 4.5 tags because setting `IsModified` to false is not possible in .NET 4.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is validation logic inside EF. The validation is always triggered on the whole entity - it doesn't respect modifications. The solution is to disable entity validation logic in EF:

```
context.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
```

Comment: Ok, at least a viable work around, but it strikes me as a bit dangerous. What more will I lose by turning this off, besides validation of non nullable fields?

Comment: You will lose whole validation but you cannot use it if you want to update only part of the entity. Validation requires you to work with whole entities filled by valid data.